# How to avoid connecting to Azure Active Directory in SpringBootApp - JUnit

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, junit5

I have a Springboot app that connects to Azure Active Directory and getting the properties from there.

I don't know exactly how the Active Directory connection works, but I am trying to write JUnits for the app without having to call the real Azure Active Directory. Whenever I run my JUnit, it keeps calling Azure.

I know I can mock the AzureCredentials class, but I really don't know how to make my JUnit use the mock even if I created a mock. None of the classes explicitly depend on the AzureCredentials class. It's somehow being called inherently.

Please guide me as to how I could JUnit this app without connecting to Azure.

```
public class AzureCredentials implements AppConfigurationCredentialProvider, KeyVaultCredentialProvider {

    @Override
    public TokenCredential getKeyVaultCredential(String uri) {
        return getCredential();
    }

    @Override
    public TokenCredential getAppConfigCredential(String uri) {
        return getCredential();
    }

    private TokenCredential getCredential() {
        return new EnvironmentCredentialBuilder().build();
    }

}
```

EDIT 14/2/2023: I've also tried by using a DUMMY connection string for the tests, but then I get this error:

```
Suppressed: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://testEndPoint was not found in the tenant named...
```

I understand the cause for this error, but I just don't want the test to try to connect at all, if there is a way to do this!